# Python BeautifulSoup - getting values within Div Select Option

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am parsing HTML from the following link: https://www.autotrader.co.uk/ where I am trying to get a full list of the makes and models within the drop down boxes.

Despite my best efforts and related BeautifulSoup questions on here I still cannot crack it. The problem is that I do not know how to call in the "options" that reside within "Select" and then within "Div".

Currently my code is as below, however only shows the first "option" and not all of them and I cannot figure out why.

```
div = soup.find('select', id='searchVehiclesMake')
print (''.join(map(str, div.contents)))
```

A slice of the HTML code can be found below:

```
            <div class="p-quick-search__make-model">
                <select class="c-form__select" name="make" id="searchVehiclesMake" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Choose a make"><option value="">Make (any)</option><option value="ABARTH">Abarth (739)</option><option value="AC">AC (3)</option><option value="AIXAM">Aixam (1)</option><option value="ALFA ROMEO">Alfa Romeo (1,721)</option><option value="ALPINE">Alpine (10)</option><option value="ARIEL">Ariel (10)</option><option value="ASTON MARTIN">Aston Martin (904)</option><option value="AUDI">Audi (31,837)</option><option value="AUSTIN">Austin (19)</option><option value="BAC">Bac (4)</option><option value="BENTLEY">Bentley (1,065)</option><option value="BMW">BMW (39,373)</option><option value="BOWLER">Bowler (6)</option><option value="BROOKE">Brooke (1)</option><option value="BUGATTI">Bugatti (4)</option><option value="BUICK">Buick (1)</option><option value="CADILLAC">Cadillac (15)</option><option value="CATERHAM">Caterham (28)</option><option value="CHEVROLET">Chevrolet (731)</option><option value="CHRYSLER">Chrysler (398)</option><option value="CITROEN">Citroen (14,009)</option><option value="CORVETTE">Corvette (5)</option><option value="DACIA">Dacia (1,413)</option><option value="DAEWOO">Daewoo (31)</option><option value="DAIHATSU">Daihatsu (123)</option><option value="DAIMLER">Daimler (21)</option><option value="DATSUN">Datsun (3)</option><option value="DAX">DAX (6)</option><option value="DE TOMASO">De Tomaso (1)</option><option value="DODGE">Dodge (126)</option><option value="DS AUTOMOBILES">DS Automobiles (1,841)</option><option value="FERRARI">Ferrari (817)</option><option value="FIAT">Fiat (10,404)</option><option value="FORD">Ford (52,166)</option><option value="GMC">GMC (4)</option><option value="GREAT WALL">Great Wall (40)</option><option value="GRINNALL">Grinnall (1)</option><option value="HILLMAN">Hillman (1)</option><option value="HOLDEN">Holden (3)</option><option value="HONDA">Honda (11,885)</option><option value="HUMBER">Humber (3)</option><option value="HUMMER">Hummer (9)</option><option value="HYUNDAI">Hyundai (12,272)</option><option value="INFINITI">Infiniti (518)</option><option value="ISUZU">Isuzu (489)</option><option value="JAGUAR">Jaguar (7,382)</option><option value="JBA">JBA (1)</option><option value="JEEP">Jeep (1,749)</option><option value="JENSEN">Jensen (2)</option><option value="KIA">Kia (13,034)</option><option value="KOENIGSEGG">Koenigsegg (1)</option><option value="LAMBORGHINI">Lamborghini (370)</option><option value="LANCIA">Lancia (14)</option><option value="LAND ROVER">Land Rover (16,759)</option><option value="LEXUS">Lexus (3,044)</option><option value="LEYLAND">Leyland (1)</option><option value="LINCOLN">Lincoln (8)</option><option value="LONDON TAXIS INTERNATIONAL">London Taxis International (16)</option><option value="LOTUS">Lotus (204)</option><option value="MARLIN">Marlin (1)</option><option value="MASERATI">Maserati (550)</option><option value="MAYBACH">Maybach (7)</option><option value="MAZDA">Mazda (8,047)</option><option value="MCLAREN">McLaren (249)</option><option value="MERCEDES-BENZ">Mercedes-Benz (31,672)</option><option value="MERCURY">Mercury (1)</option><option value="MG">MG (740)</option><option value="MICROCAR">Microcar (2)</option><option value="MINI">MINI (12,576)</option><option value="MITSUBISHI">Mitsubishi (4,791)</option><option value="MK">MK (2)</option><option value="MNR">Mnr (1)</option><option value="MORGAN">Morgan (89)</option><option value="MORRIS">Morris (12)</option><option value="NG">NG (1)</option><option value="NISSAN">Nissan (22,952)</option><option value="NOBLE">Noble (3)</option><option value="OLDSMOBILE">Oldsmobile (2)</option><option value="OPEL">Opel (5)</option><option value="PAGANI">Pagani (1)</option><option value="PANTHER">Panther (1)</option><option value="PERODUA">Perodua (16)</option><option value="PEUGEOT">Peugeot (17,586)</option><option value="PILGRIM">Pilgrim (2)</option><option value="PONTIAC">Pontiac (5)</option><option value="PORSCHE">Porsche (4,716)</option><option value="PROTON">Proton (37)</option><option value="RELIANT">Reliant (3)</option><option value="RENAULT">Renault (13,094)</option><option value="REPLICA">Replica (16)</option><option value="REVA">Reva (2)</option><option value="RILEY">Riley (3)</option><option value="ROLLS-ROYCE">Rolls-Royce (276)</option><option value="ROVER">Rover (250)</option><option value="SAAB">Saab (690)</option><option value="SANTANA">Santana (2)</option><option value="SEAT">SEAT (7,971)</option><option value="SEBRING">Sebring (1)</option><option value="SKODA">SKODA (12,077)</option><option value="SMART">Smart (1,856)</option><option value="SSANGYONG">Ssangyong (837)</option><option value="STUDEBAKER">Studebaker (1)</option><option value="SUBARU">Subaru (1,510)</option><option value="SUNBEAM">Sunbeam (1)</option><option value="SUZUKI">Suzuki (5,603)</option><option value="TESLA">Tesla (89)</option><option value="TIGER">Tiger (1)</option><option value="TOYOTA">Toyota (17,889)</option><option value="TRABANT">Trabant (1)</option><option value="TRIUMPH">Triumph (28)</option><option value="TVR">TVR (51)</option><option value="ULTIMA">Ultima (1)</option><option value="VAUXHALL">Vauxhall (41,011)</option><option value="VOLKSWAGEN">Volkswagen (33,058)</option><option value="VOLVO">Volvo (10,027)</option><option value="WESTFIELD">Westfield (5)</option><option value="YAMAHA">Yamaha (1)</option><option value="ZENOS">Zenos (7)</option></select>
                <select class="c-form__select" name="model" id="searchVehiclesModel" data-show-count="true" title="" disabled="" aria-label="Choose a model"><option value="">Model (any)</option></select>
            </div>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**** EDIT ****

In the interests of sharing what I learned from this post, I have made my project open source on GutHub, please feel free to check it out below:

https://github.com/Ben-C-Harris/AutoTrader-Web-Scraping-Used-Car-Database

Comment: findAll() -> array with all match.
find -> first result match;
json get:
https://www.autotrader.co.uk/json/search/options?advertising-location=at_cars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is built up using Javascript and a seperate XHR request to the server. If you use the network tool in a browser you can spot this happening. In this case a request is made to return JSON data from [this URL](https://www.autotrader.co.uk/json/search/options?advertising-location=at_cars).

If this is loaded using Python's JSON library, the make can accessed as a normal Python dictionary as follows:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/json/search/options?advertising-location=at_cars')
data = json.loads(req.text)

for make in data['options']['make']:
    print(make['displayName'])
```

Giving you output starting:

```
Abarth
AC
Aixam
Alfa Romeo
Alpine
Ariel
Aston Martin
```

Using this approach, you avoid needing to parse the HTML at all. You could add `print(data)` to see what the server is actually returning.

---

The models need to be requested on a per make basis, this could be done as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/json/search/options?advertising-location=at_cars')
data = json.loads(req.text)

makes = [make['displayName'] for make in data['options']['make']]
makes_models = defaultdict(list)

for make in makes:
    print(make)
    req = requests.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/json/search/options', params={'make':make})
    data = json.loads(req.text)

    for model in data['options']['model']:
        makes_models[make].append(model['displayName'])

print(makes_models['Alfa Romeo'])
```

Which would give you the following models for an Alfa Romeo:

```
['146', '147', '155', '156', '156 Sportwagon', '159', '159 Sportwagon', '164', '166', '2000', '4C', '8C', 'Brera', 'Giulia', 'Giulietta', 'GT', 'GTV', 'MiTo', 'Spider', 'Stelvio']
```

Comment: Hi Martin, that is perfect - thank you very much for your help! I have not come across the JSON data before - how did you make that link to the data?

As a continuation of my initial query, have you any ideas on how we can then impliment this technique to get the models of each respective car make?

Thanks again!

Comment: First take a look at `data` so you can see what other information is returned. Then use a browser's network tool to see what is requested when a make is selected.

Comment: Great - thanks for sharing. I have managed to do that, a great help! I can look at the model data however only for one make at a time. Any suggestions on the best way to get the data for all makes and models? Thanks!

Comment: As you have guessed, you will probably  need to request each list one at a time.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for the help Martin. Using the "Make" output you have shown above I have been able to iterate the URL for each "Make" which then outputs the respective "Models". Once I've cleaned the script up I will post on here. In the mean time I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!